# Visual Basic: Open, Save, and Save as: Into text files from textboxes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok I'm trying to get 3 buttons working, save, save as and open. Basically when a user opens the a file (optional) and they edit it (in a textbox) they can save it automatically back to that same text document or save it as a new one and continue to edit it from that new one they created. I am using 1 open file dialog and 1 save dialog, im really confused can someone please write the code for each button. please

Comment: Make sure you close the file after you load it into the textbox, otherwise you will get an error. Could you post the code that you are using to load the file?

Comment: if not resolve it see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, it is working. I created a common save routine that will check if the workingFileName is Null and open the Save Dialog box to prompt for a FileName so that it will handle both cases.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim workingFileName As String
    Private Sub Load_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Open.Click
        OfOpen.ShowDialog()
        workingFileName = OfOpen.FileName
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(workingFileName) Then
            MsgBox("FileName error please correct")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(workingFileName)
        tbText.Text = sr.ReadToEnd
        sr.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        Save_Routine(workingFileName)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Routine(fileName As String)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
            Dim sd As New SaveFileDialog()
            sd.ShowDialog()
            workingFileName = sd.FileName
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(workingFileName) Then Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(workingFileName)

        sw.Write(tbText.Text)
        sw.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveAs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAs.Click
        Save_Routine("")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Alright thanks, because it works when you load the form, although when you lets say open a file to edit, or save a new file the save as button doesnt work.

Comment: Change workingFileName to fileName in the first check for null in the Save_Routine. See edit.

Comment: Ok I changed it, but save as still isnt working, I changed it to ofOpen.Filename since filename itself gives an error

Comment: It should be the parameter that is in your Save_Routine. If you used a different name than I did use that.

Comment: You can use that if you want just don't create another one like I did. . I was just giving you working code so that you could see how it could be done.

Comment: Ok, looks like everything is perfect! I appreciate your time and help Mark. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also Mark, one more tiny thing, what code should I use to get the name of the text file that they are editing (if none it will be set to untitled)?

Comment: Get it from the fileOpen Dialog's FileName property like I did in my example. If they just started typing the name will be null so it will prompt them for a fileName just like save as

Comment: Mark, when I do that it displays the root to the textfile, how do i only make it to display the txt file itself?

Comment: Look at the path function. I am mobile right now no access to a computer. I will have to clarify further later.

Comment: Alright, but I got it so no worries thats all i need.

Comment: Mark, what if I wanted to add a New button, that clears everything, acting like the program just opened up? How would I do that? (Just like in notepad.)

Answer (score 1):

Add Save file dialog tool to your form and try:

```
Private Sub SaveAsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveAsButton.Click
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim sWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName & ".txt", False)
            sWriter.Write(tbText.Text)
            sWriter.Close()
        End If
End Sub
```

stream writer will overwrite the file.